# Dropdown menu doesn't work from tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have a code from a tutorial in youtube. I was stuck because it doesn't work while i already added its bootstrap js and others. Please help me . Thanks.

Here is the code from tutorial dropdown menu:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Site Tittle</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">

              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is links :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: You have included the bootstrap CSS files, but not the JS file.

Comment: please remove inappropriate tags - the question has nothing to do with boostrapping, doesn't contain any javascript nor jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js');?>"></script>`

you're including a js file as stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Without a working code, I can only guess.

But my guess is because of this:

```
data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"
```

Try to remove the period.

And I think navHeaderCollapse should be an id.

Comment: I'm mistaken it's not an id, it can be a class.

are you sure all scripts are loading correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and .navHeaderCollapse was correct. Don't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the bootstrap js file:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

With this line it should work.